# Why do I have debug problem with the ROS launch file problem

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I am trying to do a simple example for learning Gazebo simulation.
But while I am launching the launch file I am facing the problem which I attached as a photo.
Also, I added the codes I used as a launch file and as a world file.

[image: the terminal while launching]

```
 <!-- empty_world.launch file -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <launch>
         <!-- overwrite these args -->
         <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
         <arg name="gui" default="false"/>
         <arg name="pause" default="true"/>
         <arg name="world" default="$(find my_simulations)/worlds/empty_world.world"/>
         <!--include gazeboo_ros launcher-->
        <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
             <args name="world_name" value="$(arg_world)"/>
             <arg name="debug" value="$(arg_debug)"/>
             <arg name="gui" value="$(arg_gui)"/>
             <arg name="paused" value="$(arg_pause)"/>
             <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
        </include>
</launch>


   <!-- empty_world.world file -->
       <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <sdf version="1.5">
      <world name="default">
        <!-- A global light source -->
        <include>
          <uri>model://sun</uri>
        </include>
        <!-- A ground plane -->
        <include>
          <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
        </include>
      </world>
    </sdf>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `robotframework`, which is an acceptance-testing framework written in python.

Comment: Remove all underscores between the `arg` operator and the argument names. For example `$(arg_world)` should be corrected to `$(arg world)`.

Comment: thanks for answer there is no problem while lunching but gazbo doesn't been opened. still (waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...) @Fruchtzwerg

Comment: @hikmat.sheqully: Please do not post screenshots of error messages but instead copy & past the error as plain text. This makes it easier for us to read the question and thus makes it more likely that someone will answer it.

Answer (score 0):

`$(arg_world)` , `$(arg_debug)` ,`$(arg_pause)` and `$(arg_gui)` has typing error. remove `_` and it would be fine